# THREEJS v0.87.1: Can no longer generate tangents and binormals for use in normal mapping

Tags: three.js, glsl

I'm trying to implement normal maps in a ThreeJS fragment shader, but it seems as though a key feature, `computeTangents`, has been lost in recent versions.

Here is a working demo using an older version of Three:

http://coryg89.github.io/technical/2013/06/01/photorealistic-3d-moon-demo-in-webgl-and-javascript/

[image: Normals Working]

ThreeJS is using `computeTangents()` to add an attribute called "tangents" to the vertex which is sent to the shader.

So I researched as much as I could and tried using a shader only method of computing the tangent, but this requires `dFdx` which causes an error about `GL_OES_standard_derivatives` in the shader on my Macbook Pro.

Then I tried converting the geometry from a simple cube to buffer geometry for use in the `BufferGeometryUtils.computeTangent()` function, in order to generate the tangents there, but that requires "indexed geometry", which isn't present in basic geo created by ThreeJS.

From the original demo, this is the line I need to recreate using the latest ThreeJS:

```
 var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geo, mat);
 mesh.geometry.computeTangents();
```

Repo here:

https://github.com/CoryG89/MoonDemo

Is it possible to get this demo working using the new version of Three?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to this. For the demo above, it required changing the THREE.SphereGeometry to THREE.SphereBufferGeometry.

```
 var geo = new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry(radius, xSegments, ySegments);
```

Then I had to add the BufferGeometryUtils.js file and use the following code:

```
THREE.BufferGeometryUtils.computeTangents( geo );
```

This got the demo working again.