# ThreeJS v0.87.1 Compute tangents of a loaded OBJ file

Tags: three.js, glsl

I am trying to use the method I have working [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46734731/threejs-v0-87-1-can-no-longer-generate-tangents-and-binormals-for-use-in-normal/46738441#46738441) to add a normal map to a frag shader and calculate the tbn matrix seen [here](https://github.com/CoryG89/MoonDemo). The problem I'm running into is that you can only compute tangents on an "indexed buffer geometry". But I'm not sure how to set this and every example I've seen causes an error or a blank screen. The obj is just a very simple cube that was created in Maya. It loads correctly, but the index property is null and needs to be populated.

```
var mesh;
loader.load('Cube0.obj', function (object) {
            object.traverse(function (child) {
                 if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
                    var geometry = new THREE.Geometry().fromBufferGeometry( child.geometry );
                    var indexes = new Uint16Array(1000);


                    mesh = child;
                    var indices = new Uint16Array(geometry.faces.length * 3); // doesn't work
                  geometry.setIndex(new THREE.BufferAttribute(indices));
                  THREE.BufferGeometryUtils.computeTangents(mesh.geometry );
                }
            });

            scene.add(mesh);
        });
```

When this is all working, I should end up with a correct tangent array for each vertex which I can feed to the GLSL shader.

EDIT: I got this working and the solution is a little bit convoluted so I will try and document it here. The problem is that we don't get indices loaded along with OBJ files, as discussed here:

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/11898

One of the participants in that thread created a separate OBJ loader:

https://github.com/kaisalmen/WWOBJLoader

I ported over my OBJ load function to use this method of loading OBJs, making sure to set `objLoader.setUseIndices( true );`

Once the OBJ file loads, it now has a correctly indexed BufferGeometry. From there, I can use `THREE.GeometryBufferUtils.computeTangents(geo);`, which will add the precomputed tangent attribute to the vertex shader. This will allow me to create the "tangent, binormal, normal" matrix which can be used to correctly light the model using a normal map.

Honestly, I wish the ThreeJS OBJ loader would offer this so I wouldn't have to rely on a third party loader, but until that happens, this works.

Hope this helps someone in the future!

Comment: See `OBJLoader2.js` in the r.88dev branch.

Comment: Where is this branch? I don't see it on the main repo.

Comment: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/js/loaders/OBJLoader2.js

Comment: Ah, ok, that works. You need to also include the "LoaderSupport.js" file.